# Can not use template inside class?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I try to implement a function which received parameter type int and string. So I though of template.

Header file

```
template <typename T>
class SymbolTable {
public:
   void run(string filename);
   void insert(T value);
}
```

Implementation (.cpp) file

```
template <typename T>
void SymbolTable::run(string filename)
{
   cout << "success" << endl;
}
// Haven't implement "insert" yet!
```

Compiler report error:

```
name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name
```

If I remove template, It works fine. Any suggestion...?

Comment: Try `template <typename T> void SymbolTable<T>::run(string filename)`. Also see [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/3309790)

Comment: Your title talks about using templates *inside* a class. But your code shows a *class template*. Which is it?

Comment: *"typo"*: -> `template <typename T> void SymbolTable<T>::run(string filename)`.

Comment: Just make some edit in Header file. Sorry, It's my first post.

Comment: @TanNguyen In comparison to many other first posts yours is pretty good. You show all the code we need and the exact error. And everything as text! We don't see that too often on first posts :)

Comment: Hey, thanks. That really makes me feel good.

Answer (score 3):

This is just a basic syntax error. Your method definition should be:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void SymbolTable<T>::run(string filename)
{
   cout << "success" << endl;
}
```

Should you need it, [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/oldtutorial/templates/) are a few syntactically correct examples on how to use different variants of templates in c++.

Comment: cplusplus.com is not "the reference" but a (frequently pretty awful) site written by "enthusiasts". It's of little use unless you already know enough to tell the good bits from the bad bits.

Comment: @molbdnilo Good call, thanks for the correction. I agree my phrasing was misleading... IMO your comment on that website is completely valid if not a little harsh. It is true is asks for a lot of technical knowledge to use it in full, but they have a lot of syntactically correct examples which is nice. But the reliability of sources is a whole other opinion-based discussion...

Comment: Reliability is not a matter of opinion, it is a matter of fact, and the issues are usually with semantics, not syntax.

Comment: @molbdnilo Yeah your completely right... re-read my comment and the last sentence is pretty dumb... thanks for pointing all of that out!